# Syncing messages on frontend with missed messages in order

Tags: javascript

I have a chat component where people can send messages to each other. Everything works as expected if both users have the app active (foregrounded, backgrounded, doesn't matter). Each target user would receive a message from a source user over the socket connection.

I have a use case, where if a target user is offline, then a sent message from the source user would get queued, and upon reconnection with the server, the target user would receive all queued events, one of them being `"UNRECEIVED_MESSAGE"`, with a payload of the message itself. There are also other events that could be queued, such as `"MESSAGE_DELETED"` or `"BLOCKED_BY_TARGET_USER"`.

I've noticed, that I can easily run into an issue if a source user sends multiple messages to the, currently, offline target user. So when the target user returns online and reconnects, an "on connect" handler on my backend would query for all missed queued actions for the target user's user ID and in a loop iterate over them and send them out.

So the problem I have is that there is no guarantee that each unreceived message would reach the just-reconnected target user in the order that they were originally sent.

All received and sent messages are also stored locally in a SQLLite database, not just the application's state. Which means that once a user receives a message,

- they parse it,
- process it, and
- save it asynchronously in the database

I would like to ensure that messages are stored in the correct order that they were sent out. There is no issue with the initial local SQLLite query to populate the app's state with messages, if there are any, as I order by `id` when selecting for them.

Each message has an `id` and `created_at`, amongst other fields. My approach would be to add each message into the state, and then sort that array based on each element's `id`. So for each `"UNRECEIVED_MESSAGE"` event, I would emit the payload over the socket:

```
// backend
const queuedActions = [. . .];
queuedActions.forEach(({ action_name, action_payload }) => {
  socket.emit(action_name, action_payload);
})
```

And then on the client:

```
// frontend
socket.on(. . .);

socket.on('UNRECEIVED_MESSAGE', async (payload) => {
  await storeLocalChatMessageInDb(payload.message);

  const isInSameChat = getState().currentChatId === payload.message.chat_id;

  if (isInSameChat) {
    const messages = getState().messages.slice(0).concat(payload.message); // retrieve messages in state and clone them (because state is immutable)

    messages.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);

    setState('messages', messages); // set them back to state
  }
});

socket.on(. . .);
```

Clearly my issue with the approach above is that for ***each*** unreceived message event coming in, (which could be in the hundreds, hypothetically), I get ALL messages, clone them, sort them and then set them back to state.

Another approach that I can think of is plucking all the `"UNRECEIVED_MESSAGES"` events from all queued actions on the backend, sort them there, and then invoke only one `"UNRECEIVED_MESSAGES"` event, with the sorted array of new messages as the payload. This way, the client wouldn't have to do anything, other than just intercept the socket event and just store the payload into the state.

Is there a better way of doing this or are these my only options?

Comment: SQL doesn't have an order, you'd want to `ORDER BY created_at` in every query anyway. So what's the problem?

Comment: I prefer to order by `id` to avoid problems with dates. And it's perfect for my use case anyway, because the larger the id, the newer the message. Anyway, I specified the problem toward the bottom of the question. I also specify: `[...]if there are any, as I order by id when selecting for them.`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what `getState()` and `setState()` are doing. I was referring to "*I would like to ensure that messages are stored in the correct order that they were sent out.*" and telling you that you do not need to worry, as (relational) databases do not store anything in an "order". They just store the set of messages, and when you insert the received messages it does not matter in which order they come.

Comment: Correct, but when I initially populate the state with locally-stored messages, I do something like `select * from chat_message order by id DESC`. And AFTER that, I received "unreceived" messages via `"UNRECEIVED_MESSAGE"`. As for the `getState` and `setState` methods, these are arbitrary. I'm using `effector`, but these could also be `Redux` methods. They're arbitrary because only their lexical naming matters within the context of my current question (retrieve state and set state).

Comment: I should add that my client is using SQLLite (android/iOS) and my backend uses Postgres. Postgres holds the queued actions, SQLLite is responsible for storing messages locally (so as to not always show an empty white screen with a loader, when opening up a specific chat and retrieving all messages with a limit). Kind of like what Telegram or WhatsApp does. They store data locally and then fetch new data afterwards

Comment: Oh so you mean that when you receive the messages, you do **not** "*save it asynchronously in the database*" but actually you do want to add them to the in-memory state array?

Comment: I've update the OP, I understand where the confusion arose fom. The received "unreceived" messages get stored locally always -- the in-memory state gets updated only if an incoming message belongs to the currently opened chat (if there is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling out-of-order messages, especially when dealing with offline scenarios, can be challenging. The two approaches you've outlined are reasonable. Sorting on the backend is a good practice and reduces the workload on frontend.

One suggestion I would give is that you can use a priority queue (min-heap) to keep the messages in order based on their created_at timestamps. When a new message arrives, insert it into the priority queue. This way, you maintain the order without sorting the entire array. When extracting messages, you get the next message based on the priority. This way, you avoid sorting the entire array on each message but maintain the correct order.

Comment: Right, but if a target user has 1000 unreceived messages coming in, then, in your solution with the priority queue, I would emit 1000 times to the target user, each iteration awaiting on a "confirmation" callback from the currently-emitted message. That doesn't seem maintainable, unless I'm missing something from your approach?

Comment: In such scenarios, you might want to batch the messages on the server side and send them as a single payload. This can help reduce the number of socket events and potentially improve performance. With this approach, you still sort the messages on the backend before emitting them, but you send them as a batch to reduce the number of emitted events.

Comment: But then I don't need a priority queue, if I'll be sorting on the backend, correct? Just batched queries with a limit and current offset, then sort on the backend before emitting the messages out.

Comment: Absolutely, you're correct. If you're sorting the messages on the backend before emitting them and sending them as a batch, you don't  need a priority queue.

Comment: Yeah, I just ended up using this approach

Comment: Great work brother.